# R: Error in parse using nls

Tags: r, nls

I'm trying to fit Gaussian peaks to my density plots in R using `nls`. When I use the following equation:

```
fit <- nls(den.PA$y~coeffs2 * exp( - ((den.PA$x-coeffs3)/coeffs4)**2 ),
           start=list(coeffs2=1.12e-2, coeffs3=1075, coeffs4=2))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: ~ 
  ^
```

Can anyone point out to me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
fit <- nls(y~coeffs2 * exp( - ((x-coeffs3)/coeffs4)**2 ),data=den.PA,
       start=list(coeffs2=1.12e-2, coeffs3=1075, coeffs4=2))
```

Comment: That gave this error: cannot coerce class '"density"' into a data.frame

Comment: After googling the error I worked it out, I had to put the x and y values in their own matrix. But your answer put me on the right path :)

Comment: That work in this case, but typically one puts the values into a dataframe. This would allow for factors in general cases, e.g. lm or lme.